# How to add your app on lock screen in WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I developed an app in **WP8.1** and want to add my app on lock screen, because it gives toast notification from background task on every *geofence* change.

Comment: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/personalize-my-lock-screen

Comment: Thats for 8 not to WinRt 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You should add extension in your manifest file and use LockScreenManager in your code behind to do it.

Here is an answer and sample code:

[Windows Phone 8.1: How to programly set the detail status for lock-screen using C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f55f821c-d5bf-44c8-88ca-5e1e9ddcaab6/windows-phone-81-how-to-programly-set-the-detail-status-for-lockscreen-using-c?forum=wpdevelop)